# Why isn't "export" permanently chaning my environment variables?

Tags: fedora, environment-variables, locale

Running Fedora 20. Trying to permanently set the LANG and LC_TIME variable with "export". When I run it, it works fine and I can see it was changed. When I reboot, it gets changed back. I am doing all this though the bash shell. I have looked in .bash_profile and .bashrc in my home folder and not seeing anything where its getting this wrong value from. I also checked in /etc - the files profile and bashrc, and in /etc/profile.d/. But I cant seem to figure out where its getting that value from.

1) Where is Fedora getting the LANG and LC_TIME env variable from and how does it know which one to pick?

2) How do I change it permanently for a single user?

3) How can I change it globally(for all users) and make it stick?

4) Why does "export" not make it persistent?

I need to be able to do all of this through the shell. Thanks!

Comment: Look in `/etc/locale.conf`. That should be systemwide.

Comment: The value I want to use is actually there. But something is overriding it. Its being ignored.

Comment: When you say you exported it, you did so in some rc file and not just on the command line, right?  What file did you modify?

Comment: In bash, I did not edit any files. I ran "export LANG=en_US.utf8" for example. I think this only keeps in in RAM until you close the session. That being said, I just modified my bash_profile file in my home dir with the changes I wanted and it made it persist through reboots. I can probably figure out how to do it globally but I'm still curious where the OS gets its default information from if its not specified in any file?

Comment: Something has to be telling the OS to use xyz for the LANG env variable and where to get that. I'd like to know where that's set.

Comment: `/etc/profile` is like a `.bash_profile` used by all users, I would try adding to that.

Comment: I don't have Fedora, but see if you have an `/etc/profile.d/lang.sh`.  I'm guessing from my RHEL system here that that might be where LANG is getting set.

Comment: I have a lang.sh and a lang.csh. Honestly though, I can't make heads or tails of these files and what they are doing or where to put in my custom variables if I wanted to. And I don't explicitly see the "en_GB.utf8" locale in the file anywhere. Which, consequently, is what my env for LANG was being set to. So it must be calling it up from another file using this file.

Comment: One thing you might try is:  `find /etc/ -type f | xargs grep en_GB.utf8` and see what files in `/etc` have that string.  You could probably eliminate any in `/etc/init.d` from consideration.

Comment: Nothing in /etc/. Backed up to just / and found /var/lib/AccountsService/users/<uname>:Language=en_GB.utf8. I also setup a new account, logged in and tested it. This new account had the correct LANG locale set (en_US.utf8) so it must be coming from /etc/locale.conf as Warren T said below. Now the big mystery becomes how did my account become altered?

Comment: Ok so I removed my static entries in .bash_profile, then went to /var/lib/AccountsService/users/<uname> and changed it to "en_US.utf8". Rebooted and now env shows en_US.utf8 instead of en_GB. So problem solved.

Answer (score 4):

In bash, the "export" builtin will export the variable to the shell process's environment. Any processes started from that shell will inherit the process from that shell.

If you want the envvar to be persistent, you must set it in some place that the software started will inherit from. For the locale related vars, use /etc/locale.conf ([manpage](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/locale.conf.html)). For other variables, you will need to find another place. That place will more than likely depend on what you are trying to set the envvars for.

For example, if you want to set a environment variable for a particular systemd service, you need to add an appropriate "Environment" directive to the system unit file. See [here](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html) and search for "Environment" for more on that topic.